# How do you get the preparation redirect URL for a created Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a service account to send an envelope on behalf of another user. Using the API, I'm then creating an envelope in the "created" status for manual tab placement. Once I get the `EnvelopeSummary` back from the DocuSign API, I'd like to create a URL that I will send send back to the "send on behalf of" user so he/she can easily begin to place tabs.

I've looked into using the `CreateSenderView`/`CreateConsoleView` methods, however I don't know the `AccountId`/`Password` of the "send on behalf of" user nor do I want to use their information. Instead, I'd like to redirect the user to DocuSign where they can login and then after login, be redirected to the envelope.

I've also looked into creating my own URL from the `envelopeId`:

```
string envelopeId = "1ddff790-ad2d-4fb6-87c2-4b5e449898c9";
string redirectUrl = "https://appdemo.docusign.com/prepare/" + envelopeId;
```

This appears to redirect the user to the envelope if they are logged in, and if not, they will be prompted to login and then redirected. This is the functionality I am looking for, however, I'd like to use the API to generate this URL if possible since I'm not sure whether the referenced URL will remain static over time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you review [DocuSign API documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo) for the **Send on Behalf Of** (SOBO) feature. As the documentation describes:

- The SOBO feature can only be used when both users are members of the *same DocuSign account*.
- You (your application / UI) *must collect username and password* at least one time from the user whom you're sending on behalf of -- because you need their username and password in order to obtain an access token that can subsequently be used to submit API requests on their behalf. Since tokens do not expire (and are valid even if/when the SOBO user changes their password), you only need to collect username/password one time from the SOBO user, then use those credentials to generate an access token which can be used indefinitely to send on their behalf.

I would not recommend using the `envelopeId` to create your own URL, as this functionality is not supported by DocuSign -- even if it works today, there's no guarantee it'll continue to work in the days ahead.

Finally, issuing a [Create Sender View](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/) request (using SOBO) will return a URL that can be used to launch the sender (tagging) view for the specified Envelope. Do note, however, that the URL will expire after a short period of time (5 minutes?) -- which means that you should not issue the **Create Sender View** request to retrieve the URL until the user (sender) is ready to tag/send the Envelope. For example, issuing the request to generate the URL and then emailing that URL to the sender would not be feasible -- since there's no guarantee that the user (sender) would open the email and click the link to launch the sender view before the link expires. Instead, you should provide the sender with a way to indicate to your application when they are ready to tag/send the Envelope, and then issue the **Create Sender View** request at that time and redirect the user (sender) to that URL immediately upon receiving the URL.

---

**Update (Legacy SOBO)**

@EnterTheCode -- thank you for the clarification that you provided in the comments. Your understanding of *Legacy SOBO* functionality is correct; that is, it does not require that you obtain an access token for the SOBO and it does not require that you obtain the SOBO user's password. You can simply include the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` request header to specify the username and password of your "service account", the integrator key, and the email address (or user ID) of the user whom you're issuing the API request on behalf of.

(Side Note: Although *Legacy SOBO* is apparently still supported, it's [no longer recommended](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) for service integrations. Instead, DocuSign now recommends [this approach](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html).)

Putting SOBO authentication technique aside though, the rest of my original answer still applies to your scenario. That is, to retrieve a URL that can be used to launch the sender (tagging) view for the specified Envelope, you'll need to use the **Create Sender View** operation. And, as mentioned previously, the URL that's returned by that operation will expire after a short amount of time -- so be sure to account for that in how you design your implementation.

Comment: You mention that "the SOBO feature can only be used when both users are members of the same DocuSign account." In this case, I am using a "service account" that will do the sending for a fellow employee, and the recipient is an outside user. In addition, I'm currently using the Legacy Header Authentication. (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html) Based on the authentication in the link, it appears that you don't need to use a token. Is that the case?

Comment: @EnterTheCode thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer with additional info.

Comment: Another related question: when I create a draft envelope using SOBO, is there a way to have the DocuSign send a notification to the SOBO's email letting them know they have a document that can be edited? Currently, the SOBO account receives no indication of there being a draft envelope.

Comment: Also, the above comment is still considering the Legacy Header is being used. I've also reviewed the "Sending Notifications" configurations, and there doesn't appear to be an option.

Comment: DocuSign does not send an email when a draft Envelope is created. Your application will need to notify the sender about the draft Envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use SOBO, if you want someone to update the envelopes then you can add that user as first recipient in the envelope with recipienttype as "`Allow To Edit`" ("`editors`" in API term). With recipient type as "`Allow to Edit`", DocuSign will send an email to the recipient and then recipient has to login into his DocuSign account, after that user will be able to access the envelope and can do the editing of the envelope like doing tagging of document with DS Tabs, adding, removing recipients etc, in same way as "Sender View". In this way you don't need to create a webpage for embedded sending view.

Comment: I looked into the "Editor" recipient type. Although this may perform the requested functionality, this seems to be a workaround. Is this a recommended practice?

Comment: The difference between using the SOBO and using "Allow to Edit" is who the **sender** is for the Envelope. Using SOBO, your service account credentials are used to send the Envelope via API, but because you specify SOBO user info in the API request, that SOBO user is the **sender** -- the Envelope will be in that user's **Sent Items** folder, they can "modify" it there if necessary, and the recipient(s) see that user's name as the **sender**.  With the "Allow to Edit" approach, your service account user would be the **sender** -- recipient(s) will see that user's name as the **sender**, etc.

Comment: So, if you don't care who the **sender** of the Envelope is (i.e., are fine with your *service account* user being the sender of all Envelopes), then the "Allow to Edit" approach is feasible. But if you **do** care who the sender of each Envelope is, and you're using the *service account* credentials to send Envelopes via API, then **SOBO** is your only option.

Comment: SOBO header can be used only when that user is a member of the sending account, also now SOBO header is not a recommended approach from DocuSign, instead as @KimBrandl mentioned you need to use `User Consent` or `Admin Consent` for Service Authentication. Also If you don't care who the sender is then "Allow To Edit" is an option to go and it is used by other customers as well.